# Solve a logarithmic equation by NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve:

$$1 - |x| Log(\frac{|1+x|}{|x|}) = 0.84$$

by using NSolve:

```
NSolve[1 - Abs[x] Log[Abs[(1 + x)/x]] == 0.84, x]
```

Mathematica doesn't return anything. However other procedures, like FindRoot, gives the desired result:

```
FindRoot[1 - Abs[x] Log[Abs[(1 + x)/x]] - 0.84, {x, 0.01}]

{x -> 0.0537759}
```

How can I solve this equation by NSolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want real solutions, try adding the domain `Reals`:

```
NSolve[1 - Abs[x] Log[Abs[(1 + x)/x]] == 0.84, x, Reals]
(*  {{x -> -0.401725}, {x -> -0.0570327}, {x -> 0.0537759}}  *)
```

Over the `Complexes`, there are dimension-1 components, which may be why `NSolve` balks.  It probably ought to give an error message, so consider reporting it to WRI.

```
ContourPlot[
 1 - Abs[x] Log[Abs[(1 + x)/x]] == 0.84 /. x -> a + I b // 
  Evaluate, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Changing `Abs` to `RealAbs` also gets the real roots (`RealAbs` was introduced in V11.1): `NSolve[1 - RealAbs[x] Log[RealAbs[(1 + x)/x]] == 0.84, x]`

Answer (score 3):

You should give Mathematica a hint, "what" you are looking for:

```
NSolve[1 - Abs[x] Log[Abs[(1 + x)/x]] == 0.84, x, Reals]
(*{{x -> -0.401725}, {x -> -0.0570327}, {x -> 0.0537759}}*)
```